# adding attachment to email from browse button

Tags: c#

I'm trying to add an attachment to my email from a browse button in c#

Here is my code:

```
string fileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(),FileUploadControl.FileName);
using (FileStream fs = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead; while ((bytesRead = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) 
    {
        fs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
}

Attachment attachment = new Attachment(fileName);
msg.Attachments.Add(attachment);
```

$exception {"Stream does not support reading."} System.Exception {System.NotSupportedException}

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: you might want to accept some answers to your previous questions

Comment: i'm new to the site. would you be willing to explain to me how to accept?  i looked through my profile and i couldn't find out how to do it.

Comment: click the empty check to turn it green that accepts answers. you can see your old asked questions in your profile and check those too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got close.  You meant to read from the file input stream but didn't:

```
string fileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(),FileUploadControl.FileName);
using (FileStream fs = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead; while ((bytesRead = FileUploadControl.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) 
    {
        fs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
}

Attachment attachment = new Attachment(fileName);
msg.Attachments.Add(attachment);
```

Answer (score 1):

I was under the impression that FileUpload.FileName returns the name of the file on the **client** side, not on the server side.  You probably want FileUpload.FileBytes, which is a byte[] array.

```
string fileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(),FileUploadControl.FileName);
using (FileStream fs = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    fs.Write(FileUploadControl.FileBytes, 0, FileUploadControl.FileBytes.Length);
}

Attachment attachment = new Attachment(fileName);
msg.Attachments.Add(attachment);
```

Comment: could you help me with how and where i would implement this?

do i change this line?

string fileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(),FileUploadControl.FileName);

Comment: You don't need to be reading from the file, only writing.  You should be using FileUpload.FileBytes, a byte[] array, and **write that** to the file.

Comment: i'm sry could you send a code example based on attaching it to an email?

Comment: Ack, I edited my post to include an example after he asked. Poor user311166.   :)

Comment: int fileLength;
                    string fileContent = "";

                    fileLength = FileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentLength;
                    byte[] input = new byte[fileLength - 1];
                    input = FileUploadControl.FileBytes;

                    for (int i = 0; i < fileLength; i++)
                    {
                        fileContent = fileContent + input[i].ToString();
                    }

                    Attachment attachment = new Attachment(fileContent);
                    msg.Attachments.Add(attachment);  

FileBytes doesn't work

Comment: thanks to all that are helping me...i will just keep messing with it

Comment: string fileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), FileUploadControl.FileName); Attachment attachment = new Attachment(fileName); msg.Attachments.Add(attachment); THIS WORKED!!

Comment: This approach should work but if it's a big file it may not be ideal.  FileUploadControl.FileBytes will read the entire file into the byte array. Using FileUploadControl.PostedFile.InputStream is a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

You're reading and writing from the same file.  Go look at the example on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.saveas.aspx

Comment: im trying to attach it to my email.  i don't understand the process would you be willing to explain a little more what is wrong?

Answer (score -2):

```
Attachment attachment = new Attachment(FileUploadControl.FileName);
msg.Attachments.Add(attachment);
```

is all you need.

Comment: This is incorrect.  Read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.filename.aspx and you'll see that this is just the name of the file on the client machine.  It's not written to disk until you write it.

Comment: But he is not using the control to actually upload a file, he is just using the dialog to get a path to attach a email. there is no upload involved.

Comment: string fileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), FileUploadControl.FileName);
                    
                    Attachment attachment = new Attachment(fileName);
msg.Attachments.Add(attachment);

THIS WORKED!!

Comment: It worked only because it was on your local machine.  You didn't upload anything!

Comment: Unless you *expect* the client to always be the same machine as the server, this is only working by coincidence.  It is not a correct answer.